# [Label compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, core-data

My app is crashing with the error `unrecognized selector sent to instance` and simply highlights `@main` in my App swift file, which doesn't give me any clues as to what may be causing the error.

I think it might have to do with conflicting data in a @FetchRequest.  I've isolated the error to these snippets of code:

```
struct SidebarView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Label.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Label.name, ascending: true)])
    var labels: FetchedResults<Label>

    var body: some View {
        let allLabelNames = labels.map { "\($0.value(forKeyPath: "name")!)" }
        let labelNames = allLabelNames.uniqued()

         VStack{
             NavigationLink(destination: AllDataView(names: labelNames)){
                Text("View all data")
         }
    }
}
```

```
struct AllDataView: View {
    var imagesFetchRequest: FetchRequest<Sample>
    var images: FetchedResults<Sample>{
        imagesFetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }
    private var names: [String]

    init(names: [String]){
        let samplesSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Sample.label, ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label.name IN %@", names)
        self.names = names
        imagesFetchRequest = FetchRequest<Sample>(entity: Sample.entity(), sortDescriptors: [samplesSortDescriptor], predicate: predicate)
    }
}
```

Note that Label is a `NSManagedObject`

Any ideas for how to debug this issue to find the exact line in my app that's causing it to crash?

Comment: Give the full error message.

Comment: `NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Sample.label, ascending: true)` => `NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Sample.label.name, ascending: true)`? You are trying to sort on `label` property which is a `Label`. So it will a some point compare a `Label` instance to another one, calling `compare()`, which doesn't work in your case... You want to compare on the name property.

Comment: Thanks @Larne! that was the issue.  if you add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Sample.label, ascending: true)
```

=>

```
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Sample.label.name, ascending: true)
```

In the first one, you are trying to sort `Sample` on its `label` (`Label`) property.
So a some point, it will do `[someLabelInstance compare:someOtherLabelInstance]` to know if which one needs to be put before the other one. But, `Label` doesn't have an instance method `compare()`, that's why you get the error.
You want in fact sort on the `name` property of that `label`. Property which is a `String` (implicit by reading your code), and is "sortable" (implements `compare()`).